# No transaction in progress in user details service using Spring Boot

Tags: spring-mvc, transactions, spring-boot

I'm working on a new application using Spring Boot, Spring Data, and Cas Authentication. Everything has been working fine, including transactions. However, I recently discovered that the Custom Authentication User Details Service class I have is not transactional (all other service classes are fine).

My Boot config:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
```

The service class in question:

```
@Service
@Transactional("transactionManager")
public class CustomAuthenticationUserDetailsService implements    AuthenticationUserDetailsService<CasAssertionAuthenticationToken> {

    @Autowired OtherEntityService entityService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserDetails(CasAssertionAuthenticationToken token) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        OtherEntity entity = entityService.find(1L);
        entity.setEntityName("test2");
        entityService.save(entity);
```

In this example I'm injecting the other service class, I get the same result if call the save method of an injected otherEntityRepository directly.

```
@Service
@Transactional("transactionManager")
public class OtherEntityServiceImpl extends BaseServiceImpl<OtherEntity> implements OtherEntityService {

@Autowired OtherEntityRepository otherEntityRepository;

@Override
public OtherEntity save(OtherEntity entity) {
    return otherEntityRepository.saveAndFlush(entity);
}
```

Part of web security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.myapp.test"})
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Value("${cas.url}")
private String casUrl;

@Value("${site.url}")
private String siteUrl;


    @Bean
    public ServiceProperties serviceProperties() {
        ServiceProperties serviceProperties = new ServiceProperties();
        serviceProperties.setService(siteUrl + "j_spring_cas_security_check");
        serviceProperties.setSendRenew(false);
        return serviceProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public CasAuthenticationProvider casAuthenticationProvider() {
        CasAuthenticationProvider casAuthenticationProvider = new CasAuthenticationProvider();
        casAuthenticationProvider.setAuthenticationUserDetailsService(authenticationUserDetailsService());
        casAuthenticationProvider.setServiceProperties(serviceProperties());
        casAuthenticationProvider.setTicketValidator(cas20ServiceTicketValidator());
        casAuthenticationProvider.setKey(casUrl + "/cas");
        return casAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationUserDetailsService<CasAssertionAuthenticationToken> authenticationUserDetailsService() {
        return new CustomAuthenticationUserDetailsService();
    }
```

The result is:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: no transaction is in progress.
```

I only get the transaction error when I save and flush. Otherwise a valid authentication token is created and the user proceeds but nothing is persisted from this service class (even the authenticated user if they are a new user).

I've searched for similar issues and have not found a solution. It seems to be a configuration issue. Spring is aware of this service (since I can autowire it) but the @Transactional annotation is not creating a transaction.

The only component scanning I have explicitly declared is on the datasource configs and the web security config classes.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I can be useful to have the full stack trace available.